# Command line subversion client for Windows Vista 64bits

Tags: windows, svn, windows-vista, 64-bit

Does anyone recommend any particular command line SVN client for Windows. Being 64 bits would be a bonus.

I do have TortoiseSVN, but it doesn't come with command line, which is required for my build scripts. I searched the subversion site and found not one, but four different options. Therefore, my question.

Comment: TortoiseSVN has "command line client tools" . Unchecked by default during installation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) ([download](http://www.sliksvn.com/pub/Slik-Subversion-1.7.4-x64.msi)) looks like the most appropriate option given what you want.

Answer (score 3):

They aren't 64-bit, but the official Collabnet binaries work fine in 64-bit Windows:
http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

Comment: They don't. I've had localization issues with them on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

Again its not 64-bit but this is a good open source client http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

Comment: This does not receive updates anymore. There are only unsupported SVN versions.

Answer (score 2):

Run again the installer for TortoiseSVN. Select "Modify", then you can select to install also the otherwise optional Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Beware compatibility among versions.  if you cmd line commit, you can cause yourself unexpected problems for say, Hudson/Jenkins automated builds if the svn versions are not compatible.
See e.g. [Jenkins: invalid version of SVN working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107857/jenkins-invalid-version-of-svn-working-copy/) 
Some might think it ironic, that a versioning system has backwards compatibility issues that can bite you :)