# Tortoise SVN, how to get the update view back?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When you do an update in tortoise, you get the view that says what files are updated, merged, conflicted and so on.

Then you can fix those things right there, edit conflict and so on...

If you accidantely press ESC that window dissapears. How do I get back to a view like that?

I know I can do show modifications, but that is not the same thing. That will all the files that have been changed in your workspace, and that can be alot!

Any tips?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. I usually use, as you pointed out, `check for modifications` and sort by the Date column.

Comment: Good idea. Its to bad though. Sometimes you update in the end of the day, and you have to keep the window open and in the way until you deal with it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't make this dialog reappear.

However you can use command-line:

[`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.update) will show you all the updated/merged/added files, and give you possibility to resolve conflicts on-the-fly or to postpone them to be resolved later:

```
$ svn update
A added_file
U updated_file
D deleted_file
...
```

The output will be kept in the console or saved to the log file, so it can be review later.

After the update, you can use [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine) to show all the modified files in the working copy, including files with conflicts, that will be marked with `C` in the first column:

```
$ svn status
M locally_modified_file
C file_with_a_conflict
```

Comment: I am guessing you are on a linux computer. I am not, hence tortoise. Command line stuff is not that easty in windows :(

Comment: @Hamidam, you'll be surprised, [there](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) are [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341134/command-line-svn-for-windows) SVN command-line clients for Windows.
E.g. I've personally tried [CollabNet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) and from the fast view I don't see any difference from the Linux subversion client. 
So, if you want more power and flexibility, it worth trying.