# After installing Tortoise SVN still showing error in android studio (Project is newly imported from another system )

Tags: android, android-studio, svn

I tried all the examples provided but still the same problem. Can you please solve this issue?
**Steps that I followed**

1. imported the android studio project to my android studio.
2. while building the gradle it statrs to error. the i searched about the problem in google
3. Then [i tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341134/command-line-svn-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341134/command-line-svn-for-windows) and i installed the [svn from](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/latest/download?source=typ_redirect) then i started my android studio then it shows the same error.
   [This is what i getting while i starts ma android studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed2hi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the correct path to `svn.exe` you've specified a path to your Gradle build file. That's why Android studio is unable to run SVN client.