# svn.remote.RemoteClient.info: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, svn

I am trying to connect SVN remote client and get the latest committed revision with following python codes in Windows:

```
r = svn.remote.RemoteClient(svnPath)
revNum = str(r.info().get("commit#revision"))
```

I am getting following error:

> in \n    revNum = str(r.info().get("commit#revision"))\n', ' 
>   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\svn-0.3.45-py3.6.egg\svn\common.py",
>   line 75, in info\n    do_combine=True)\n', '  File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\svn-0.3.45-py3.6.egg\svn\common.py",
>   line 54, in run_command\n    return self.external_command(cmd,
>   environment=self.**env, **kwargs)\n', '  File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\svn-0.3.45-py3.6.egg\svn\common_base.py",
>   line 25, in external_command\n    env=env)\n', '  File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init**\n
>   restore_signals, start_new_session)\n', '  File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child\n
>   startupinfo)\n']: [WinError 2] The system
>   cannot find the file specified

I tried to print the "`svnpath`" and "`r`" to make sure it goes correct. I got as expected the correct remote server path (lets say "`remote_path`") for "`svnpath`" and `< SVN(REMOTE) remote_path>` for "`r`".

The remote SVN needs credential (UID & PWD) to access. However, the machine I use this script to run has already SVN setup with correct credentials. 
Do I need to still specify explicit credential in python scrip to access? If so then how? Or do I need any extra python package for SVN?

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and fixed it by installing an SVN command line and adding it's path to the PATH environment variable.

If you're on Windows, you can install the command line executable when installing Tortoise SVN, but by default the corresponding option is not checked (see [ccpizza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686341/5812729)).

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved your issue by then but looking at the code might help.

The class `RemoteClient` inherits from `CommonClient` which starts like this:

```
class CommonClient(svn.common_base.CommonBase):
    def __init__(self, url_or_path, type_, username=None, password=None, 
                 svn_filepath='svn', trust_cert=None, env={}, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommonClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   ...
```

Therefore, the following should work:

```
import svn.remote

url = "http://server.com:8080/svn/SuperRepo/branches/tool-r20"

client = svn.remote.RemoteClient(url, username="toto", password="SuperPassword")
print(client.info())
```

Comment: Not working for me. error , " [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified "

Comment: Just to double check: you are sure that the path exists?

Comment: Path is exists.  I can  checkout through Tortoise svn client.