# SVN update through command line

Tags: svn, command, teamcity, line

I want to update my SVN-Project before I start the build-procces. I need to reach this goal through the windows command line. Unfortunately I cannot find the command. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you want to run the [`svn update`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/update/) command, but you don't have svn.exe on your computer.

You need to install the Subversion client and make sure that it was added to the [%PATH% environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). If you are on Windows, you can grab the latest command line tools from https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/.

If by some reason you still cannot run the svn.exe command line client, you need to specify what's happening on your side in your question and give more details & context.

Comment: I am using TortoiseSVN but I don't see svn.exe. Ty, I will try it out

Comment: @Thomassek then see this, please https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686341/761095

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot. it works now. I appreciate your help!