# Jenkins: invalid version of SVN working copy

Tags: svn, jenkins

Our build server runs Jenkins 1.502 with Subversion plugin upgraded to version 1.45. This plugin uses `svnkit-1.7.6-jenkins-1.jar`.

Also we have SVN client 1.7.8 installed.

Jenkins successfully checks out source code from SVN repository. But when I go to workspace directory and try to run some svn command manually, it fails:

```
# cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject/workspace/
# svnversion
svn: E155036: Working copy '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myproject/workspace' is too old (format 8, created by Subversion 1.4)
```

The error message indicates that working copy was created by SVN 1.4, but version of svnkit is 1.7.6. How could it be?

I searched entire file system, there are no any other `svnkit-*.jar` files.

Comment: Have you tried checking out a fresh workspace after the upgrade instead of using one which was created before upgrade?

Comment: @ShivaKumar, I can upgrade workspace and then work with it. But I wonder why it is created in version 1.4. This prevents me to use automatic tools.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There is an option in jenkins to tell svn which working copy format to use(manage jenkins > configure system), look for a 'Subversion Workspace Version' pulldown - it's likely set to 1.4. change it to the latest version in the list.

Comment: This did the trick. Just needed to blow away the repos to let the change take effect

Comment: The repos are in [jenkins]/workspace/jenkins-project-name

Comment: After making the above change, you can fix up existing repos from the command line with `svn upgrade`. See svn source file [wc.h](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_wc/wc.h) for the non-obvious mapping of svn client version to working copy format.

Comment: Many thanks for this! Shame it is hidden in such an obscure place - there should at least be some pointer to that from either the plugin install information or the configuration section on jobs.

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't able to downgrade subversion to 1.7. (due to dependencies).

Another way to fix this is add a "Pre Step / Execute Shell" with command `svn upgrade` respectively `cd trunk; svn upgrade` in the job configuration.

This works with subversion 1.8.8 
on Ubuntu 14.04.