# Jenkins, Maven Release Plugin and SVN

Tags: svn, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am using the Maven Release Plugin for Jenkins to make a release. I am getting the following error:

```
    message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.2:prepare (default-cli) on project kobv-albert-frontend-dkfz: Unable to check for local modifications
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/svn-lokal-dkfz/workspace' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)

cause : Unable to check for local modifications
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/svn-lokal-dkfz/workspace' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)

Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.2:prepare (default-cli) on project kobv-albert-frontend-dkfz: Unable to check for local modifications
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
svn: E155036: Working copy '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/svn-lokal-dkfz/workspace' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
```

I tried to `svn upgrade` but it doesn't help. I also tried different versions of the `maven-release-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.2</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

It does't help either. What could be causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you tried looking at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107857/jenkins-invalid-version-of-svn-working-copy

Comment: Thanks, looked this post, but it is not what i need.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem as in the OP and the solution suggested in the link posted by Fausto solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problems. I solved it by using the same svn-client for the release-plugin as jenkins uses.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <providerImplementations>
      <svn>javasvn</svn>
    </providerImplementations>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

But you have to clean your job-workspace once after configuring this.

Comment: How do I find out what version of SVN Jenkins is using? I've been all over.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which version of Subversion that Jenkins is using - you just need to ensure that the version of the `maven-scm-provider-svnjava` you specify supports the same version of Subversion your code base is using - see major Subversion release compatibility here https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/maven-scm-provider-svnjava/

Answer (score 0):

CI System (Jenkins/Hudson) leverages the subversion(svn) installed on the system at which ci runs. 
When it gives the error: Working copy at x/y/z is too old (format 8/10/11) to work with client version 'x.y.z (ie. 1.9.4). You need to upgrade working copy first. There are two solution for this either update the "Subversion Workspace version (svn version)" to matching to the format of local installed svn version. In case ci has not support to the local installed svn , then you will need to downgrade or upgrade the version of local installed svn to match with svn version of jenkins. ci does not work with the latest version of svn, it uses slight lower version.

If you are using svnkit inside or leveraging the environment variables through any container(eclipse, webserver, tomcat, osgi..) and env-variables are properly working, then you need to restart the container so that it can take/reload the values of env-variables.

"The svn command failed. svn is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file". i was facing issues with svn when trying to automate build with jenkins. Basically i downgrade the local svn to resolve above problem and did not restart the tomcat, and i was facing this issue. So after restarting the tomcat, it start picking up the svn command and it worked successfully.

Using Jenkins 1.7.1, OS: Window 8.x, Java: 1.8.x 64bit, Tomcat 8.x, Stablized svn 1.8 version for jenkins and local installed svn client version; 26-Jul-2016 vinod bherwal.